# How to write from a FILE* to a fd?

Tags: c, file, shared-libraries

I would like to copy the content of a `FILE*` file (a `*.so` library) into a file descriptor that I'll give to an other function. I've read about `fileno()`, but it doesn't seem to work properly. 
Could anyone give me a trick to do that ?

Here is my code :

```c
int takeFromDisk(char *file){
    int shm_fd;
    shm_fd = open_ramfs(); // Give me a file descriptor to memory
    printf("[+] File Descriptor Shared Memory created!\n");

    FILE *fichier = fopen(file, "r");


    fclose(fichier);
    return(shm_fd);
}
```

And the function I'm using to have my file descriptor :

```c
int open_ramfs(void) {
    int shm_fd;

    //If we have a kernel < 3.17
    // We need to use the less fancy way
    if (kernel_version() == 0) {
        shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
        if (shm_fd < 0) { //Something went wrong :(
            fprintf(stderr, "[-] Could not open file descriptor\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    // If we have a kernel >= 3.17
    // We can use the funky style
    else {
        shm_fd = memfd_create(SHM_NAME, 1);
        if (shm_fd < 0) { //Something went wrong :(
            fprintf(stderr, "[- Could not open file descriptor\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return shm_fd;
}
```

And the code I tried :

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fichier)) != EOF)
{
  write(shm_fd, &c, sizeof(c));
}
```

Comment: 1) you can use open() instead of fopen() to directly get an FD; 2) if fileno() "isn't working properly" it would help if you shared the code you tried with it and what the result was...

Comment: @JanKrüger I would like to copy the content of the variable fichier to the file descriptor shm_fd that I have created using open_ramfs()

Comment: Did you try to `fread` from the `FILE *` and `write` to the file descriptor?

Comment: @coco: so what code did you write that didn't work?

Comment: @dbush I want to do the exact opposite ...

Comment: @coco I edited the comment right after I posted it.  Take another look.

Comment: @coco sure, and there are many ways to do that, some more efficient than others, but my impression was that you're having trouble with setting up the basics - if that's the case, a little more detail would help - like what code you've tried that isn't working. After that, the easiest (and also least efficient) way would be to loop over a duo of `fread` and `write` calls...

Comment: @rici I erase the "code" I wrote in the takeFromDisk() function, my goal is to take the content of fichier and put it in the file descriptor shm_fd

Comment: *I would like to copy the content of a FILE* file (a .so library) into a file descriptor that I'll give to an other function*  Seems like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You have another problem ("an other function") and you've decided on your solution and are trying to force it.  What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: @JanKrüger I've added the code I tried in my post ;)

Comment: `write(shm_fd, (void *)c, sizeof(c));`  Ouch.  When your compiler complains about an incorrect type, blindly adding a cast doesn't really fix anything.  You're writing the first byte of the *address* of `c` to the file instead of the *contents* of `c`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code you tried is a problem of pointer arithmetic.

- `fgetc` returns the byte you read as a value, which you store into `c`. So far, so good.
- `write` is a little more flexible than `fgetc` - it can write more than one byte at a time (similar to `fread`). So you can't just pass it a single integer value as you tried to do - it needs a *pointer* to a memory location with the byte you want to write. `&c` is a pointer to the memory used by `c` - but wait, that's not all yet...
- `fgetc` returns the byte it reads in an `int`. On all modern platforms, `int`s are larger than one byte, so that variable `c` is actually *more than* a byte (most systems you'll encounter have 4 bytes in an `int`, which is also what your `sizeof` will produce, so you'll end up with a file inflated by factor 4). Unfortunately, platforms differ in where exactly the byte you care about is found in the memory for that variable. On many platforms using `&c` will work, but not on all.
- The better approach is to allocate a fixed-size buffer, then you can read into it with `fread` and write it into the other FD using `write`, approximately like this (I left out error handling and other details):

```c
#define BUFSIZE 4096
char buf[BUFSIZE];
while (1) {
    size_t num_read = fread(&buf, 1, BUFSIZE, fichier);
    if (num_read == 0) break;
    write(shm_fd, &buf, num_read);
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there are much more efficient approaches to copy data from one file to another. On Linux, there is a dedicated system function for this, it's called `sendfile`. On other systems you can map one of the files into virtual memory to simplify things, using `mmap`, which is less efficient but still better than the manual version using a buffer.